# What is the best HTML to PDF convertor that can be used by a .NET web app?

Tags: .net, pdf, reporting

What is the best HTML to PDF convertor that can be used by a .NET web app? We would like to leverage our existing web skills to produce reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not do a full comparison. I can only say that our own converter [WebToPDF.NET](http://www.tallcomponents.com/webtopdf2.aspx) has a very high conformance level, comparable to that of the major browsers. See the W3C test reports:

http://test.csswg.org/harness/review/CSS21_CR/

Hit the Go button (it will take a while...). We are in the right-most column, WebToPDF.